# Issues getting pdf from latex code generated by kable() in r markdown environment

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, conditional-formatting

I am trying to get a pdf document including a conditionally formatted table using kable() and kable_styling) as described here : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html.

I encounter errors when I do so (see code). It seems that the Latex code generated by kable() is the cause.

Attached to this post you can find :

- a r markdown code that creates the html file
- a r markdown code that should create the same document as the HTML code but in .pdf

Here is the table I would like to get in a pdf document : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mojNa.jpg

````
---
title: "testhtml"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    highlight: tango
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    theme: united
    toc: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
if (!require(tidyverse)) {install.packages("tidyverse")}
library(tidyverse)
if (!require(knitr)) {install.packages("knitr")}
library(knitr)
if (!require(kableExtra)) {install.packages("kableExtra")}
library(kableExtra)
if (!require(tinytex)) {install.packages("tinytex")}
library(tinytex)
#Data sample
risque_alpha = 0.05
synthese_ex <- structure(list(campagne = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2017", class = "factor"), 
                              prelevement = structure(c(1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200,
                                                        1504483200, 1504483200, 1504483200, 1504483200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
                                                      tzone = "UTC"), 
                              profondeur = c("-110", "-90", "-70", "-50", "-30", "-10", "-110", "-90", "-70", "-50"), 
                              test_applique = c("ANOVA","Kruskal-Wallis", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "Kruskal-Wallis",
                                                "Kruskal-Wallis", "Kruskal-Wallis"),
                              p_value_test = c(0.2691, 0.16966, 0.29958, 0.25323, 8e-05, 0.00214, 0.70138, 0.45697, 0.69763, 0.65208)),
                         row.names = 2:11, class = "data.frame")
#conditional formatting
options(knitr.table.format = "html") # ....................... for pdf this causes a prolem!?
tab_synthese <- synthese_ex %>% mutate(p_value_test = cell_spec(p_value_test, color = ifelse(p_value_test < risque_alpha, "green","red"))) %>% kable(escape = FALSE, booktabs = T, linesep = "") %>% kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
tab_synthese
```
````

If run the Rmd above as html you get

> Fehler: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting
>   latex output. Please change the output type of this document to HTML.
>   Alternatively, you can allow HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding
>   this option to the YAML front-matter of your rmarkdown file:
>     always_allow_html: yes
>   Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML
>   formats.
>   Ausführung angehalten

## Code to generate the pdf error :

````
---
title: "testpdf"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    highlight: tango
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    theme: united
    toc: yes
#always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
if (!require(tidyverse)) {install.packages("tidyverse")}
library(tidyverse)
if (!require(knitr)) {install.packages("knitr")}
library(knitr)
if (!require(kableExtra)) {install.packages("kableExtra")}
library(kableExtra)
if (!require(tinytex)) {install.packages("tinytex")}
library(tinytex)
#Data sample
risque_alpha = 0.05
synthese_ex <- structure(list(campagne = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2017", class = "factor"), 
                              prelevement = structure(c(1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200,
                                                        1504483200, 1504483200, 1504483200, 1504483200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
                                                      tzone = "UTC"), 
                              profondeur = c("-110", "-90", "-70", "-50", "-30", "-10", "-110", "-90", "-70", "-50"), 
                              test_applique = c("ANOVA","Kruskal-Wallis", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "Kruskal-Wallis",
                                                "Kruskal-Wallis", "Kruskal-Wallis"),
                              p_value_test = c(0.2691, 0.16966, 0.29958, 0.25323, 8e-05, 0.00214, 0.70138, 0.45697, 0.69763, 0.65208)),
                         row.names = 2:11, class = "data.frame")
#conditional formatting
options(knitr.table.format = "latex") # ....................... for pdf this causes a prolem!
tab_synthese <- synthese_ex %>% mutate(p_value_test = cell_spec(p_value_test, color = ifelse(p_value_test < risque_alpha, "green","red"))) %>% kable(escape = FALSE, booktabs = T, linesep = "") %>% kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
tab_synthese
```
````

## Code to generate something very close to the targetted document

It seems that the problem comes from the `kable_styling()` function. Please note that the `options(knitr.table.format = "")` part has been removed and replace by `format = "pandoc"` in the `kable()` function.

````
---
title: "testpdf"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    highlight: tango
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    theme: united
    toc: yes
always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
if (!require(tidyverse)) {install.packages("tidyverse")}
library(tidyverse)
if (!require(knitr)) {install.packages("knitr")}
library(knitr)
if (!require(kableExtra)) {install.packages("kableExtra")}
library(kableExtra)
if (!require(tinytex)) {install.packages("tinytex")}
library(tinytex)
#Data sample
risque_alpha = 0.05
synthese_ex <- structure(list(campagne = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2017", class = "factor"), 
                              prelevement = structure(c(1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200, 1509667200,
                                                        1504483200, 1504483200, 1504483200, 1504483200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
                                                      tzone = "UTC"), 
                              profondeur = c("-110", "-90", "-70", "-50", "-30", "-10", "-110", "-90", "-70", "-50"), 
                              test_applique = c("ANOVA","Kruskal-Wallis", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "ANOVA", "Kruskal-Wallis",
                                                "Kruskal-Wallis", "Kruskal-Wallis"),
                              p_value_test = c(0.2691, 0.16966, 0.29958, 0.25323, 8e-05, 0.00214, 0.70138, 0.45697, 0.69763, 0.65208)),
                         row.names = 2:11, class = "data.frame")
#conditional formatting
tab_synthese <- synthese_ex %>% mutate(p_value_test = cell_spec(p_value_test, color = ifelse(p_value_test < risque_alpha, "green","red"))) %>% kable(format = "pandoc", escape = FALSE, booktabs = T, linesep = "") %>% kable_styling( "striped", full_width = F)
tab_synthese
`
````

``

Comment: `p_value_test` is unknown. What is it?

Comment: it is a column with numerical values. The text in this column is colored depending on the value of the cell.

Comment: Please provide everything so that i have a reproducible example.

Comment: I am working on a way to make it more easier to use. I will edit the code above when it will be done. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Good idea - have a look, that you get a **minimal** example: Throw everything out which is not relevant to reproduce the error. Sometimes this solves the problem ;-)

Comment: Well, the codes above should reproduce the error with a simple copy/paste in the RStudio markdown environment. Does it work ?

Comment: See my edit: You can have html and pdf in one doc. Just select the button in RStudio! The problem is with "option html". Do you really need that? Have a look at `DT::datatable(mydata)...

Comment: the `options(knitr.table.format = "html")` is the default option for the funtion `kable()`. If I set `options(knitr.table.format = "latex")` as described in the tutorial link (http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) I get an error `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.143 campagne & prelevement & profondeur & test_
                                                 applique & p_value_test\\ '

Comment: If I allow HTML figures in the pdf document, the figure is not formatted... If I understand the package DT provides HTML tables. I would like to get a pdf as the HTML is not a problem here.